# How to ignore Rust executable files in .gitignore?

Tags: rust, gitignore

I'm learning Rust and doing small exercises following the tutorial.

When I compile and build using `rustc`, it generates an executable file.

I want to add only the `.rs` file under the project/chapter1, chapter2, etc. directories and ignore the executables generated by the `rustc` command.

I don't know how to do that because the executables generated by Rust do not have any extension.

How can I ignore these executables using .gitignore?

Comment: You could ignore everything _except_ for .rs files.

Comment: Jhpratt - how can is do that?

Comment: In your gitignore, have two lines. One is `*`, which ignored everything. The other would be `!*.rs`, which tells git to _not_ ignore .rs files.

Comment: jhpratt - I tried this. that doesn't help me :(

Answer (score 6):

If you follow the instructions in the [official Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), you will do all of your work using Cargo. The book [introduces Cargo in the first chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch01-02-hello-world.html#creating-a-project-with-cargo). 99.5% of Rust developers never use `rustc` directly, and doing so is simply going to lead you to pain.

Cargo automatically sets up a directory structure where build artifacts go into the `target` directory and this directory is added to `.gitignore`. You have nothing else to do.

---

You could do the same thing by hand and ignore the build output directory (you really shouldn't though, it's not worth it to avoid Cargo)

```
$ mkdir target
$ rustc -o target/example example.rs
$ ./target/example
$ echo 'target/' >> .gitignore
```